# Custom menu including also primary menu items

Tags: menus

I just would like to show my "footer menu" only with the two pages I manually added in appearance section:

`register_nav_menu('footer', 'Footer menu');`

[image]

but when loading in the footer:

```
 {!! wp_nav_menu([
            'menu' => 'Footer menu',
            'theme_location' => 'Footer menu',
            'menu_class' => '']
     ) !!}
```

it keeps listing all the pages, also taken from Primary one :(

any adivce?

ty

Answer (score 0):

In my function:

```
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'menu-1' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'mySite' ),
            'menu-2' => esc_html__( 'Secondary Menu', 'mySite' ),

        )
    );
```

And then in my header to display the menu:

```
<?php
wp_nav_menu(
array(
'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
)
);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`theme_location` is supposed to be the menu slug, not the label. You've given it the label.

For `register_nav_menu('footer', 'Footer menu');` the menu location name is `footer`. So you need to use:

```
'theme_location' => 'footer',
```